# Android handling multiple notifications without collision

Tags: android, android-notifications

Im using the following mechanism in order to avoid broadcasting the same notification Id to the system.

```
int directInstallCompleteNotificationId = GlobalPrefUtils.getSharedPref().getSharedPrefsInt(PREF_NOTIFICATION_INSTALL_COMPLETE, 0);

directInstallCompleteNotificationId++;

GlobalPrefUtils.getSharedPref().setSharedPrefsInt(PREF_NOTIFICATION_INSTALL_COMPLETE, directInstallCompleteNotificationId);
```

Is there a way to have android handle the incrementation of ids?

Comment: From my point of view, sending multiple messages which are equal shows poor software design. I suggest you to redesign your structure so each single state inside your app has and sends only one distinct notification, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the notification id as `System.currentTimeMillis()`, this will always be unique and there will not be any collision between the notifications of your app

Comment: does the value returned by  System.currentTimeMillis() never surpass the value allowed?